# Unexpected behavior of a Postgres query with a JSONB column update inside a CTE

Tags: postgresql, update, cte

```
WITH deleted_files AS (SELECT name
                               FROM files
                               WHERE id = $1),


     updated_links AS (

         UPDATE links l
             SET object = JSONB_SET(object, '{files}', (SELECT jsonb_agg(elem)
                                                             FROM files nested,
                                                                  jsonb_array_elements(object -> 'files') elem
                                                             WHERE nested.id = l.id
                                                               AND elem ->> 'name' != (SELECT name FROM deleted_files)),
                                    true) RETURNING id, object)

DELETE FROM links WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM updated_links WHERE object IS NULL);
```

I am using Postgres 14 and running this query inside of a Goland query session with READ COMMITTED isolation level.

The idea of this query is to:

1. Get deleted file names by `id`
2. Update the `object` JSONB column in the table `links`
3. Delete rows from `links` where after this update the value of `object` (JSONB field) is `NULL`.

As a result of this query, I still see rows with NULL `object` fields even though if I just do something like `SELECT id FROM updated_links WHERE object is NULL` instead of the delete statement, I get the right results.

It seems that the statement after CTEs doesn't yet see the updated columns but that is a bit strange given that the changes are apparently visible to SELECT statements.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why would `object` be `NULL` it's more likely to be `'{"files":null}'` which is not the same thing. Sample data and expected results would help, even a full https://dbfiddle.uk